# Unable to filter out javascript tagged scenarios using cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I need to run my cucumber rails (capybara) suite without scenarios that use the @javascript tags.

I'm using the command

```
bundle exec cucumber --tags not @javascript
```

and when I run this it's almost as if the command is accepted but it runs no scenarios

```
No such file or directory - @javascript. You can use `cucumber --init` to get started.
```

when I try

```
bundle exec cucumber --tags @javascript
```

it does run the @javascript tagged scenarios only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working syntax is `bundle exec cucumber --tags 'not @javascript'`.